# Failed to parse a String to int

Tags: java, parsing

I don't know what's wrong with parsing the String to an int part in my code.   Before the parsing, everything looks correct.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class TheWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        String s = "13.16";
        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        System.out.println(d);
        char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
        char[] ch2 = new char[s.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++){
            if(ch[i] == '.'){
                break;
            }else{
                ch2[i] = ch[i];
            }
        }
        String s2 = new String(ch2);
        System.out.println(s2);
        try{
            s2.trim();
            int newI = Integer.parseInt(s2);
            System.out.println(newI);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the error message say?  If you wanted to know what went wrong it is a good idea to read it rather than discard it.  I suspect your `ch2` has some nul chars at the end, you break the loop but you don't make `ch2` any smaller.  You can use your debugger to step through the code to work out what each line is doing and where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are breaking out of the for loop when the '.' character is reached.

Since you created `ch2` with a length of 5 then this means the last three spaces are null. When you put that in a string with `String s2 = new String(ch2)` then then three special characters are added at the end of the string, one for each empty space in the `ch2` character array.

To fix this then set the length of the `ch2` array to be two, or if you want to dynamically determine the length, do the index of the '`' in the`String s`with`s.indexOf('.')`and then set the length of the array to one minus the index of '`'.

This should fix your problem as stated in your question.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You are not storing the returned `String` from `trim()` anywhere. You could either do:

```
s2 = s2.trim();
int newI = Integer.parseInt(s2);
```

or

```
int newI = Integer.parseInt(s2.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s2 = s2.trim();
```

change this part of code in the try block.

You are trimming the string but not assigning it to the variable that refers it due to which the spaces are still left out and parsing such string is throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Java objects are immutable, meaning they can't be changed, and Strings are Objects in Java.

Your line `s2.trim()` will return the trimmed version, but `s2` will not be directly modified. However, you aren't storing it anywhere, so when you parse it on the next line, it will be with the untrimmed `s2`.

What you want is `s2 = s2.trim()`, which will store the trimmed version back in.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to truncate the decimal. If so, then you can just find the decimal place and substring the string, then parse it.

Note: You might want to add back in some try-catches for strings that still cannot be parsed.

```
private static int tryParseInt(String str) {
    int decimalIndex = str.indexOf(".");

    if (decimalIndex != -1) {
        return Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, decimalIndex));
    } else {
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(tryParseInt("13.16")); // 13
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have uninitialized characters in your ch2 array. You can set them to space before trimming or use a different string constructor. For example:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "13.16";
        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        System.out.println(d);
        char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
        char[] ch2 = new char[s.length()];
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < ch.length; i++){
            if(ch[i] == '.'){
                break;
            }else{
                ch2[i] = ch[i];
            }
        }
        String s2 = new String(ch2, 0, i);
        System.out.println(s2);
        try{
            s2.trim();
            int newI = Integer.parseInt(s2);
            System.out.println(newI);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    }
```

}